# My mini van overheating after 150 km of drive

Tags: overheating

Radiator replaced and gaskit is also replaced.. It's overheating but when i drive at 60km/h it's normal but when I park it's overheating..

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the fans to ensure they are operating correctly? Non-running fans are usually what causes what you describe.

Comment: Is 150km the speed you are driving at? As you then mention 60km/h

Comment: 150km I drive the car. At 60km/h.. Fan, radiator, water pump, thermostat valve is checked and working fine.. After 3 hours of drive its starts over heating while car is not moving.. But wen I push the race or moving the car temperature starts reducing.. Anyone can help please

Comment: Check that the radiator cap is the correct one for your vehicle and that it will hold the pressure that it is supposed to. If your vehicle has a reservoir do not fill above the recommended levels for hot/cold operation. Check the operation of the fan. [Edit] your question to include Make/Model/Motor and year of your vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

If the car is not overheating while moving, I think the problrm is in the fan. Usually cars with broken fan overheat while stationary because there is not enough air going through radiator to cool it down.

Comment: I consult with the machanic but still he is not able to tell  what is the fault. According to his knowledge he said that there is water cerculation issue while fan,water pump, and thermostat valve is fine..

Comment: Yeah it's possible that the coolant circulation isn't right.

Comment: Please help me how to solve this water cerculation system

Comment: @Rameez Hayat it's not sure if the problem is in coolant circulation, it can be many things, radiator, thermostat, water pump, clogged pipes and so on. It's better if you go to mechanic.

Comment: Hi asnem.. Water pump is working fine as the machanic said. And thermostat is newly installed.. Pipes are cleaned by the machanic.. Radiator is changed already.. Car runs 200k already. Model 2016 daihatsu gran max.. Even the machanic can't find that heating fault yet.. Do u think I should added coolant only?. Bcz I'm using only normal water in the radiater and the reservoir.. Is there any chances that water is damgeging the sencers? Or there any other issue with heating problem.?

Comment: Machanic put the fan on full speed already.. When car heating up.. I use to give full race to the engine.. In this case it comes to its normal temperature but after 5 minutes again same thing happen..

Comment: Water can cause rust and freeze in cold and damage your pipes, however get a new thermal sensor maybe your sensor isn't reading right and car is not really overheating.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem; the iron block contained thick rust deposits . While the car was running it is good . But when stopped ,water trapped in some locations would increase the temperature shown on the gage and boil out of the radiator cap . The water would be brown with rust deposits . The whole cooling system needs to be cleaned.